# Can you use accessor methods in overloaded operators?

Tags: c++, methods, operators, overloading, accessor

So I've always been taught that good coding practice is to use accessor methods versus directly accessing member variables, however while writing overloaded operators, I cannot compile if using these accessor methods within the operator class definition. So assume the following class:

```
    class Point
    {
    public:
        Point() {};
        virtual ~Point() {};

        // Accessor Methods
        inline void SetX(ushort nX) { m_nX = nX; }
        inline void SetY(ushort nY) { m_nY = nY; }
        inline ushort GetX() { return m_nX; }
        inline ushort GetY() { return m_nY; }

        // Overloaded Operators
        Point operator+(const Point& pnt);

    private:
        ushort m_nX, m_nY;
    };
```

In the operator definition, the following seems perfectly legal, but it goes against what I've been taught:

```
    Point Point::operator+(const Point& pnt)
    {
        Point myPoint;
        myPoint.SetX(GetX() + pnt.m_nX);
        myPoint.SetY(GetY() + pnt.m_nY);
        return myPoint;
    }
```

However, the following compiles with the error:

> Point.cpp:7:36: error: passing 'const Point {aka const Point}' as 'this' argument of 'ushort Point::GetX()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>
> Point.cpp:8:36: error: passing 'const Point {aka const Point}' as 'this' argument of 'ushort Point::GetY()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
    Point Point::operator+(const Point& pnt)
    {
        Point myPoint;
        myPoint.SetX(GetX() + pnt.GetX());    // Here I am trying to use accessor methods vs. member variables
        myPoint.SetY(GetY() + pnt.GetY());
        return myPoint;
    }
```

The latter code will compile if the 'const' keyword is removed from the parameter list, which I don't fully understand, just because I'm passing in a const variable, why does that eliminate my ability to use the accessor methods?

Comment: Your member `operator+` should be `const` qualified as well. You are not modifying the this argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your getter functions are not marked as const, so cannot be called on a constant object:

```
inline ushort GetX() const { return m_nX; }
                     ^^^^^
```

Without the `const` keyword, the compiler must assume that the function might modify the object, and thus cannot be called on a constant object.  It's also good to note that in some cases, you may want both a `const` and a non-`const` version, with different return types, such as:

```
const_iterator vector<T>::begin() const; //const version
iterator vector<T>::begin(); //mutable version
```

Using getters and setters is (in my opinion) more correct than accessing the right hand sides's members directly.

Comment: +1. I think the key point is that C++ doesn't *know*, unless you tell it, that these are just getters, and that it's safe to call them on a `const` object. (This is a good thing; it means that you can't accidentally write code that calls a method on a `const` object unless you *intend* for the method to be `const`-safe, rather than, say, it's just temporarily `const`-safe because right now it's just an empty stub.)

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
inline ushort GetX() { return m_nX; }
inline ushort GetY() { return m_nY; }
```

to:

```
inline ushort GetX() const { return m_nX; }
inline ushort GetY() const { return m_nY; }
```

The compiler is complaining that an attempt is being made to call a `non-const` method on a `const` object.